# how to generate pdf with dompdf or any other libraries, where html and php are writen together?

Tags: php, dompdf

Because assigning a value to the "$html" with whole code which is written with php and html is tedious. Is there any way? or can we make whole page as pdf directly?

Comment: You can prind whole page as pdf, check google for 'wkhtmltopdf'

Comment: you can try with html2pdf library - https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your use case. For example, if the page you want to render to PDF can be accessed via a web server then you can just load that page in your Dompdf script:

```
// include dompdf then ...
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html_file("http://example.com/document.php");
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```

If the content and Dompdf logic needs to all be on the same page then you can use output buffering to capture the HTML and feed it to Dompdf:

```
ob_start();
// HTML + PHP to create output
$html = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();

// include dompdf then ...
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
```